# Resize image to fit the tab

Tags: android, image, tabs, resize

I am using two different images for two tabs. But the images are not filling the tabs. there are some empty spaces shown. I want the images to occupy the tab

Comment: show your layout file here.. n with the image is much appreciable

Comment: @vandana your answer is best.

Comment: @Anbu369 you got best answer just accept it as best.

Comment: @vnshetty Really sorry for my late reply... Here is my tab.xml file http://txtup.net/yZdh

This is my TabActivity.java file http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=dRXQA

and this is the final output I get <http://imgur.com/XGizo>
I couldnt make the images fit inside the tab completely. any ideas?
sorry i didnt know how to embed codes in comment

Answer (score 2):

You must use "fill_parent" in your xml code:-

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```